# Port localhost:3000 does not respond

Tags: windows, command, port, meteor

I use Windows and I ran the .msi.

`localhost:3000` does not respond. I activated and rested iis and cannot see anything under 3000. How can I check if the port is active and if anybody s listening? I tried `lsof -i` in cmd and I get the error "lsof unrecognized batch file"

Also, when I run meteor from the directory with the example or dummy, I do not have anything else following like

> ..running, port localhost:3000 active

It doesn't look like the command 'meteor' does anything on my machine.

Do I need to put my meteor folder inside the installation one (i.e. `C:/Program Files(x86)/meteor`)

Comment: Did you reboot? You either need to reboot or manually set up the environment variables Meteor needs, or the command line won't work.

Comment: `localhost:3000` wont respond until you have a meteor instance running. After your reboot if you run `meteor create --example leaderboard` from command prompt does it do anything? Btw is this a 64 bit or Windows 8 machine?

Comment: You can use tcpview (live.sysinternals.com/tcpview.exe) to check if something is listening on 3000.

Comment: @rahul ,@akshat I rebooted yesterday and even put IIS(IIS is not needed is it), however it didnt work(the meteor command did not produce anything). Today it does, but I am stuck. I get the following after running meteor: running on localhost:3000, then Exited with code:-1073741819,Exited with code:-1073741819, then new line I cannot write anything or press enter or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted, Meteor has gotten an official Windows installer. See if it works now.